# How to join two MySQL tables based on the same column name?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 different tables. Both have several different columns, but there's a column `serial_number` that is in both these tables with duplicate serial numbers.

In the table 1, I want to append the row data of table 2 if the `serial_number` matches in both the tables.

Example:

Table 1

```
id, serial_number, name  , phone     , email
 1, 87454126     , Chris , 5105487451, example@example.com
```

Table 2

```
id, serial_number, status   , reason
 1, 87454126     , Completed, Some Reason
```

#### The result I want:

**Table 1 changes to:**

```
1, 87454126, Chris, 5105487451, example@example.com, Completed, Some Reason
```

Kindly help me, I can't figure this out. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you want to alter table 1

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.)

Comment: ...which we're only too willing to do

Comment: Whatever your exact sticking point when isolated--(Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give both tables a different name and join like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.serial_number = t2.serial_number;
```